# why is JPA using incorrect column name in insert statement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to insert a record into a table using the JPA. I get an error from postgres that a column name is incorrect. The column in question is a foreign key to another table.

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "location_id" of relation "device" does not exist
  Position: 125
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO public.device (ASSETMGR, CIIM, CREATEDDATE, ISDISPOSED, MODIFIEDDATE, NDV, PARTNUMBER, SERIALNUMBER, TAGNUMBER, LOCATION_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

What I expected is for the insert statement to use 'location' not 'location_id' and in fact I double checked to see if there was a 'location_id' column name specified in the project and could not find one. I use lowercase for all column names in the database.

Can someone point to why the JPA infrastructure is trying to insert into a field that doesn't exist in code? Thanks!

Here's the Device class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractDevice implements java.io.Serializable
{

    // Fields

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7363521382735742845L;
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer id;
    private Integer ciim;
    private Integer assetmgr;
    private String serialnumber;
    private String partnumber;
    private String tagnumber;
    private Timestamp createddate;
    private Timestamp modifieddate;
    private Integer ndv;
    private Location location;
    private Boolean isdisposed;
    private Set<LocationReport> locationReports = new HashSet<LocationReport>(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public AbstractDevice()
    {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public AbstractDevice(Integer id, String serialnumber,
            Timestamp createddate, Timestamp modifieddate, Boolean isdisposed)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.serialnumber = serialnumber;
        this.createddate = createddate;
        this.modifieddate = modifieddate;
        this.isdisposed = isdisposed;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public AbstractDevice(Integer id, Location location, Integer ciim,
            Integer assetmgr, String serialnumber, String partnumber,
            String tagnumber, Timestamp createddate, Timestamp modifieddate,
            Integer ndv, Boolean isdisposed, Set<LocationReport> locationReports)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
        this.ciim = ciim;
        this.assetmgr = assetmgr;
        this.serialnumber = serialnumber;
        this.partnumber = partnumber;
        this.tagnumber = tagnumber;
        this.createddate = createddate;
        this.modifieddate = modifieddate;
        this.ndv = ndv;
        this.isdisposed = isdisposed;
        this.locationReports = locationReports;
    }

    // Property accessors

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ciim")
    public Integer getCiim()
    {
        return this.ciim;
    }

    public void setCiim(Integer ciim)
    {
        this.ciim = ciim;
    }

    @Column(name = "assetmgr")
    public Integer getAssetmgr()
    {
        return this.assetmgr;
    }

    public void setAssetmgr(Integer assetmgr)
    {
        this.assetmgr = assetmgr;
    }

    @Column(name = "serialnumber", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getSerialnumber()
    {
        return this.serialnumber;
    }

    public void setSerialnumber(String serialnumber)
    {
        this.serialnumber = serialnumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "partnumber", length = 128)
    public String getPartnumber()
    {
        return this.partnumber;
    }

    public void setPartnumber(String partnumber)
    {
        this.partnumber = partnumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "tagnumber", length = 16)
    public String getTagnumber()
    {
        return this.tagnumber;
    }

    public void setTagnumber(String tagnumber)
    {
        this.tagnumber = tagnumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "createddate", nullable = false, length = 29)
    public Timestamp getCreateddate()
    {
        return this.createddate;
    }

    public void setCreateddate(Timestamp createddate)
    {
        this.createddate = createddate;
    }

    @Column(name = "modifieddate", nullable = false, length = 29)
    public Timestamp getModifieddate()
    {
        return this.modifieddate;
    }

    public void setModifieddate(Timestamp modifieddate)
    {
        this.modifieddate = modifieddate;
    }

    @Column(name = "ndv")
    public Integer getNdv()
    {
        return this.ndv;
    }

    public void setNdv(Integer ndv)
    {
        this.ndv = ndv;
    }

    @Column(name = "isdisposed", nullable = false)
    public Boolean getIsdisposed()
    {
        return this.isdisposed;
    }

    public void setIsdisposed(Boolean isdisposed)
    {
        this.isdisposed = isdisposed;
    }


    @Column(name = "location")
    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    public Location getLocation()
    {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setLocation( Location location )
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Set<LocationReport> getLocationReports()
    {
        return this.locationReports;
    }

    public void setLocationReports(Set<LocationReport> locationReports)
    {
        this.locationReports = locationReports;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "AbstractDevice [id=" + id + ", ciim=" + ciim + ", assetmgr="
                + assetmgr + ", serialnumber=" + serialnumber + ", partnumber="
                + partnumber + ", tagnumber=" + tagnumber + ", createddate="
                + createddate + ", modifieddate=" + modifieddate + ", ndv="
                + ndv + ", locationReports=" + locationReports + "]";
    }
```

Here's the DDL for the device table:

```
CREATE TABLE device
(
  ciim integer, -- Corresponding CIIM table id.
  assetmgr integer, -- Corresponding asset manager record identifier.
  serialnumber character varying(32) NOT NULL, -- A unique hardware identifier identifying this particular piece of equipment among all others from the same vendor.
  partnumber character varying(128), -- Vendor supplied part number defining this particular type of unit.
  tagnumber character varying(16), -- Tag identifier that identifies the asset for capital management purposes. Can be null and can be duplicated among different serial numbers.
  createddate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  modifieddate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  ndv integer DEFAULT nextval('device_seq'::regclass), -- foreign key to the device table in the NDV db
  id serial NOT NULL,
  location integer, -- fkey to location table
  isdisposed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT device_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT device_location_fkey FOREIGN KEY (location)
      REFERENCES location (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "DEVICE_SERIAL_U" UNIQUE (serialnumber)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE device
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.ciim IS 'Corresponding CIIM table id.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.assetmgr IS 'Corresponding asset manager record identifier.
';
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.serialnumber IS 'A unique hardware identifier identifying this particular piece of equipment among all others from the same vendor. ';
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.partnumber IS 'Vendor supplied part number defining this particular type of unit.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.tagnumber IS 'Tag identifier that identifies the asset for capital management purposes. Can be null and can be duplicated among different serial numbers.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.ndv IS 'foreign key to the device table in the NDV db';
COMMENT ON COLUMN device.location IS 'fkey to location table';


-- Index: device_serialnumber_idx

-- DROP INDEX device_serialnumber_idx;

CREATE INDEX device_serialnumber_idx
  ON device
  USING btree
  (serialnumber COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

-- Index: fki_device_location_fkey

-- DROP INDEX fki_device_location_fkey;

CREATE INDEX fki_device_location_fkey
  ON device
  USING btree
  (location);
```

This is the primary key column for AbstractLocation.java which is what device.location is a foreign key to.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractLocation implements java.io.Serializable
{

    // Fields

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8336411995952512794L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Integer id;
    @Column( name="building
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a default `OneToOne` mapping for the `AbstractDevice.location` field. The default `JoinColumn.name` value, as defined by the JPA spec, is

> The concatenation of the following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the referenc- ing entity or
>   embeddable class; "_"; the name of the referenced primary key column.

In this situation, the default is `location_id`.

To change this, you must specify a `JoinColumn`:

```
@JoinColummn(name="location")
private Location location;
```

Comment: '@JoinColumn(name="location")
private Location location;'   I kept looking at the relationship annotations for the answer. ( e.g.:  @ManyToOne )

Comment: The spec can be irritating that way. All the various annotations are not explicitly correlated to each other. I guess it's more "flexible" that way. :-) Also, I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer, if appropriate.